# Drop Subscriber at SQL Transactional replication

Tags: replication, transactional-replication

We have SQL Transactional pull replication:

Publisher and Distributor are at the same server - **ServerA**.

It publicates **Publication1**.

Pull Subscribers to Publication1 are - **ServerB**, **ServerC** and **ServerD**.

How can I completely drop let say *ServerD* as subscriber only, so no more left overs, no logs grow at *ServerA*, no alerts some commands are not replicated etc.? The rest replication to *ServerB* and *ServerC* must be in tact and going without any downtime.
What should be correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the subscription from Server D:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/delete-a-pull-subscription?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: And the correct sequence is as per MS doc? 1. Delete a pull subscription at the at **Publisher**. 2. Delete a pull subscription at the  **Subscriber**? 
No need to run commands like `sp_removedbreplication` at any side ?

Comment: It "should" be straightforward and as the doc describes. If you're using SSMS UI then you'll have the option to connect to the publisher/subscriber to cleanup from there as well (depending where you're deleting from). If you're using T-SQL then start at the subscriber and then the publisher afterwards, again following the doc. A word a caution because it has happened, I have had occasions where replication metadata has remained afterwards and it's caused a mess; subscriptions don't disappear from replication monitor for example. If you can test this on a lower environment first then please do!